# Ayuda Navigation Drawer Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo mi menu desplegable con sus respectivos items. Pero me gustaria agregarle a cada item el TextView que se ve en la imagen que dice ESTRENOS. Como lo puedo agregar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la imagen de como me queda ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: identifica cual es el layout.xml de tu NavigationDrawerItem y modificalo agregando otro TextView, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

En tu layout del "item" agrega otro `TextView` donde tu puedas agregar el texto "Estrenos", este es un ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_subway"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:text = "Seccion"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text = "Estrenos"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

@NicolasSchmidt, te recomiendo veas el ejemplo de este link :
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/ que publiqué en otra respuesta, tu vista la puedes configurar, en este caso agregar el `TextView` para que aparezca el texto "Estrenos", ver `drawer_list_item.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre es que crees un nuevo `layout` con el textview i.e texto_estreno.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Estrenos"/>
```

Ya después en tu `DrawerMenu` `item` puedes hacer referencia al layout donde está el `Textview`, i.e:

```
<item  app:actionLayout="@layout/texto_estreno"   />
```

De esa manera lo puedes costumizar el layout donde está el texto "Estrenos 
" a tu gusto, colores, estilos, tipo de fuente, etc.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Otra forma que no es la  mejor es hacerlo con `SpannableString`:

No estoy seguro con el número de los caracteres, ya es cuestión que le coloques el número que corresponde:

```
NavigationView navigation = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation);
Menu menuNav = navigation.getMenu();
MenuItem element = menuNav.findItem(R.id.item5); //Aquí colocas tu item
String before = element.getTitle().toString();

String texto = "Estrenos";
String s = before + "   "+texto+" ";
SpannableString sColored = new SpannableString( s );

sColored.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan( Color.GRAY ),3, 3,  0);

sColored.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan( Color.WHITE ), 3, 3,0);


element.setTitle(sColored);
```

Comment: Hice lo que me dijiste, pero me lo muestr abajo a la derecha, no me lo muestra en la misma linea de codigo

Comment: te dejo la imagen en una respuesta

Comment: Te sugiero que borres esa respuesta  y colócalo en comentarios, edité  mi respuesta. Otra cosa, colocaste la referencia del  layout en el item del texto "hola"?

Comment: Mira en esta parte:  `<item  app:actionLayout="@layout/texto_estreno"   />` me refiero a que por ejemplo tienes el item con el texto "hola" ahí mismo dentro de ese mismo item colócale  `app:actionLayout="@layout/texto_estreno"`  y no crees otro item, no se si me entiendes.

Comment: me lo puedes escribir? gracias

Comment: No puedo, pero es fácil, dentro del `item` que quieres que aparezca solo agrégale esta línea:   `app:actionLayout="@layout/texto_estreno"`, solo agrégale no debes de crear otro item.